# wireshark capture filter for specific UDP bytes

Tags: udp, wireshark

I need a capture filter for wireshark that will match two bytes in the UDP payload.  I've seen filters with

```
UDP[8:4]
```

as matching criteria but there was no explanation of the syntax, and I can't find it in any wireshark wiki (needle in the haystack thing).

I need to only capture UDP 5361, and only packets that have the bytes 8C:61 as the third and fourth bytes in the payload. Something like

```
udp port 5361 and udp[2:2]=8C:61
```

But I'm guessing at this of course. Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 6):

Stumbled on it:

```
udp port 5361 and udp[10:2]==0x8C61
```

UDP data field (payload) starts at offset 8, and I'm looking at payload bytes 3 and 4.  The tip was in WireShark Wiki, after all.

Comment: But it would also be nice to be able to wildcard the offset, so that I could match two bytes anywhere in the UDP data, instead of the second and third...

Comment: Wildcarding would require either that [the BPF machine language](http://www.tcpdump.org/papers/bpf-usenix93.pdf) (into which capture filters are compiled) support loops (which is *not* supported for kernel BPF code, and almost certainly never will be, as it'd let you make the kernel BPF interpreter loop infinitely) or that it have a byte-string-matching instruction.  It's probably not likely to happen any time soon, as it'd involve significant changes to libpcap and to various OS kernels.